# Why aren't nav bar buttons centered?

Tags: html, css, web

I have the code [there](https://jsfiddle.net/efv8x1x2/)
My question is, why aren't the buttons for different pages centered? This is more obvious when the site is minimized.

```
nav.stroke ul li a,    
nav.fill ul li a {    
position: relative;
}
nav.stroke ul li a:after,
nav.fill ul li a:after {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 0%;
  content: '.';
  color: transparent;
  background: #aaa;
  height: 1px;
}
nav.stroke ul li a:hover:after {
  width: 100%;
}

nav.fill ul li a {
  transition: all 2s;
}

nav.fill ul li a:after {
  text-align: left;
content: '.';
 margin: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}
nav.fill ul li a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 1;
}
nav.fill ul li a:hover:after {
  z-index: -10;
  animation: fill 1s forwards;
-webkit-animation: fill 1s forwards;
  -moz-animation: fill 1s forwards;
  opacity: 1;
}

h1,h3 {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}
li{
  list-style-position: inside;
  display: inline;
  padding-left: 12px;
}

a{
 padding: .2em .1em;
color:grey;
  background-color: ;
}


}
.xy{
  margin-top: 75px;
}
h1{
  font-size: 45px;
}
h3{
  font-size: 23px;
}
body{
  background-color: #451255;
}
nav {
  width: 70%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 0px #dedede;
  position: center;
}
nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}
nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}
nav ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #aaa;
  font-weight: 800;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: 0 10px;

}
nav ul li a,
nav ul li a:after,
nav ul li a:before {
  transition: all .5s;
}
nav ul li a:hover {
  color: #555;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fill {
  0% {
    width: 0%;
    height: 1px;
  }
  50% {
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #451255;
  }
}
.btns,
.fill{
    margin: auto;
    position: center;
    display: block;
}
```

So, I have that code, you can see on the link what it looks like. My problem is that it's not centered. And when I minimize it, the fact that it's not centered is more obvious. How could I fix that?

Comment: `position: center` doesn't exist! You have to use `text-align: center` applied to the parent container of your buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like @junkfoodjunkie already said, it's about basic CSS reset.
why? elements got initial CSS set, this is what's going on:
[image]

like you can see, your menu's items (blue part) are already centered but you've got initial `-webkit-padding-start: 40px;` (green part) and it's do the same as `padding-left: 40px;`, it takes not less than 40px from your menu so that's why it looks like the menu's items are not centered/stick to the right, so in order to fix it you need to overwrite the value of the `<ul>` element.
you're also set the `<li>` elements to `padding-left: 12px;` so the menu's items will not be centered perfectly. if you're not going to use some [CSS reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) then add `.fill > ul {padding-left: 0;}` to your CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You're not resetting or eliminating default behavior. You have no `margin` or `padding` defined on the `<ul>`, and you have not reset the CSS to begin with, so there is a default padding and margin messing with you. Put `margin: 0; padding: 0;` on your `<ul>` and it should work.

Or, just do a full brutal reset: https://jsfiddle.net/efv8x1x2/1/

Added

```
* {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
```

to the beginning of the stylesheet, and voila, centered.

Comment: It worked when I messed with your fiddle, but perhaps I did something more. I would still suggest you do a reset to begin with, and modify the code after.

Comment: It does work - well, at least a brutal reset does. See updated answer.